# C# Selenium how to get outerhtml of a element's all childs

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, innerhtml, outerhtml

Here's a html code;

```
<div id="div-f2qqs">
   <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      ....
   </table>
   <div class="head-2"></div>
      <p></p>
      <li></li>
  </div>
```

I want to get all `div-f2qqs`'s child of outerHTML. How can I do it can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
(//div[@id='div-f2qqs']).GetAttribute("outerHTML");
```

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 1):

### outerHTML

The [**outerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) attribute of the [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can also be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string.

Ideally to obtain the HTML representation of the contents of an element you should be using the [**innerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property instead.

---

To obtain the `outerHTML` you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.div-f2qqs")).GetAttribute("outerHTML"));
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='div-f2qqs']")).GetAttribute("outerHTML"));
  ```