# Scraping and writing the table into dataframe shows me TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scraping the table and write in a dataframe they show me a `typeerror`. How to resolve these errors?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
temp=[]
driver= webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.fami-qs.org/certified-companies-6-0.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='Inline Frame Example']")))
headers=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='sites']//thead"))).text
rows=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='sites']//tbody"))).text
temp.append(rows)
df = pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=headers)
print(df)
```

In headers I pass the data `FAMI-QS Number`  ... `Expiry date` while in rows I will pass the `FAM-0694`  ...  `2022-09-04`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **scrape** all the data from all the columns you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) of the *`<table>`* element, extract the [outerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954602/c-selenium-how-to-get-outerhtml-of-a-elements-all-childs/69955173#69955173), read the outerHTML using `read_html()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.fami-qs.org/certified-companies-6-0.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='Inline Frame Example']")))
  data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#sites"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
  df  = pd.read_html(data)
  print(df)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [  FAMI-QS Number                             Site Name              City  ... Status Certified from Expiry date
  0       FAM-1293                    AmTech Ingredients        albert lea  ...  Valid     2020-10-08  2023-10-07
  1       FAM-0841                    3F FEED & FOOD S L       vizcolozano  ...  Valid     2020-04-17  2023-04-16
  2       FAM-1361                5N Plus Additives GmbH  eisenhüttenstadt  ...  Valid     2020-10-01  2023-09-30
  3    FAM-1301-01                   A & V Corp. Limited            xiamen  ...  Valid     2020-09-09  2023-09-08
  4       FAM-1146  A. + E. Fischer-Chemie GmbH & Co. KG         wiesbaden  ...  Valid     2020-06-05  2023-06-04
  5       FAM-1589          A.M FOOD CHEMICAL CO LIMITED             jinan  ...  Valid     2020-01-07  2023-01-06
  6    FAM-0613-01                          A.W.P. S.r.l        crevalcore  ...  Valid     2020-02-27  2023-02-07
  7       FAM-0867             AB AGRI POLSKA Sp. z o.o.           smigiel  ...  Valid     2020-08-03  2023-03-19
  8    FAM-1510-02                              AB Vista       marlborough  ...  Valid     2020-04-16  2023-04-15
  9    FAM-1510-01                            AB Vista *         rotterdam  ...  Valid     2020-04-16  2023-04-15

  [10 rows x 7 columns]]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all table data from api calls html response using only pandas as follows:

Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://famiqs.viasyst.net/certified-sites"

req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

table = pd.read_html(req.text)

df = table[0]#.to_csv('info.csv',index = False)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    FAMI-QS Number  ... Expiry date
0          FAM-0694  ...  2022-09-04
1          FAM-1491  ...  2022-10-17
2     FAM-ISFSF-003  ...  2022-10-27
3          FAM-1533  ...  2022-10-31
4          FAM-1090  ...  2022-11-13
...             ...  ...         ...
1472    FAM-1761-01  ...  2024-10-27
1473       FAM-1796  ...  2024-09-29
1474    FAM-1427-01  ...  2023-12-01
1475       FAM-1861  ...  2024-11-22
1476    FAM-0005-07  ...  2024-11-25

[1477 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

To **scrape** the *FAMI QS Number* and *Site Name* column you need to create a list of the desired texts using [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945168/access-to-table-objects-on-webpage-using-python-selenium/69947765#69947765) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.fami-qs.org/certified-companies-6-0.html")
  FAMI_QS_Numbers = []
  Site_Names = []
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='Inline Frame Example']")))
  FAMI_QS_Numbers.extend([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='sites']//tbody//tr/descendant::td[1]")))])
  Site_Names.extend([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='sites']//tbody//tr//td/p")))])
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(FAMI_QS_Numbers, Site_Names)), columns=['FAMI QS Number', 'Site Name'])
  print(df)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
    FAMI QS Number                             Site Name
  0       FAM-1293                    AmTech Ingredients
  1       FAM-0841                    3F FEED & FOOD S L
  2       FAM-1361                5N Plus Additives GmbH
  3    FAM-1301-01                   A & V Corp. Limited
  4       FAM-1146  A. + E. Fischer-Chemie GmbH & Co. KG
  5       FAM-1589          A.M FOOD CHEMICAL CO LIMITED
  6    FAM-0613-01                          A.W.P. S.r.l
  7       FAM-0867             AB AGRI POLSKA Sp. z o.o.
  8    FAM-1510-02                              AB Vista
  9    FAM-1510-01                            AB Vista *
  ```