# Can't use Selenium to find elements. Try to avoid deprecated commands warning, got result only one element. (on Colab)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

As my title said. To avoid deprecated warning of Selenium.I try to use the new format as I found.
and somehow result return only 1 element. How can I fix it to return elements?
FYI I scraping website. I'm working on Colab so I can share with my workmates easier.

**Here my code**

```
#!pip install selenium
#!pip install IPython
#!pip install pandas
#!apt-get update
#!apt install chromium-chromedriver

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
website = 'https://www.bitkub.com/fee/cryptocurrency'
driver.get(website)

#pull_data
coins = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'tr')
```

**checking what element it contains (which somehow got only 1)**

```
print(coins)
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="091bac0ea46529043f4d84786ebc705f", element="76396e66-6516-4dd0-9d85-bc66bfad4676")>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally **`coins`** should have been a list of elements.

However, to extract the name of the ***coins*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.bitkub.com/fee/cryptocurrency')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody tr td:nth-child(2) span")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.bitkub.com/fee/cryptocurrency')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr//following::td[2]//span")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks, your method so so helpful. but can I use pandas to make Dataframe out of it? or Do I have to create a dictionary or something to sort it first?

Comment: @Visushi_Tiramitsu Ofcoarse you can make a Dataframe out of it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70160219/7429447) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

What is occuring is that you need webdriver waits and wait for visibility for all elements.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
trs = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "tr")))
```

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
```