# How to scrape the Current Holdings table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scraping:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
import pandas as pd

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r'C://Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C://geckodriver.exe' , options=options)


url = 'https:/'
driver.get(url)

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'dgtopHolders')))
dfs = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
print(dfs[0])
```

How can I scrape this table ?
thanks for your time

best

Comment: You could try saving the page to HTML and parsing it? Or is the issue that you have to go through the rows 50 at a time? There are only 52 rows in your specific example so this shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: I am seeking a solution. Everythings is ok. The right solution is the uniwue request

Comment: the number of row is not a problem. i prefer 50 row, but it's not a problem

Comment: I don't find the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oww8E.png) either in [this](https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_link) or [this](https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_linksta) link, am I missing something obivious?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium You have to click a button which runs some Javascript. There's no direct link to the page (unless you cheat as per the answer(s) below).

Comment: @BarryCarter Whao, I doubt if there is any way you can cheat with Selenium as Selenium strives for visibility of any element at the least.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I was answering your question as to why the table wasn't in either link. There is no direct link to the table, at least not an obvious one. You can "cheat" by looking at what URLs the page itself calls when you click on Whitelist, but that's different

Comment: @BarryCarter Your tip helped me to construct an answer. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: tes! there is the table!!" https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_link  "let scroll the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *scrape* the data from the ***current holdings_table*** as the `<table>` is present with the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) but not visible within the webpage, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) for the *`<table>`* element, extract the [outerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954602/c-selenium-how-to-get-outerhtml-of-a-elements-all-childs/69955173#69955173), read the outerHTML using `read_html()` and you can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://whalewisdom.com/filer/berkshire-hathaway-inc#tabholdings_tab_link'})
  # data = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#current_holdings_table").get_attribute("outerHTML")
  data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#current_holdings_table"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
  df  = pd.read_html(data)
  print(df)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [    Stock  Unnamed: 1                  Sector  ...  Source Source Date  Date Reported
  0    AAPL         NaN  INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  1     BAC         NaN                 FINANCE  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  2     AXP         NaN                 FINANCE  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  3     CVX         NaN                  ENERGY  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  4      KO         NaN        CONSUMER STAPLES  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  5     OXY         NaN                  ENERGY  ...       4  2022-05-02     2022-05-04
  6     KHC         NaN        CONSUMER STAPLES  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  7     MCO         NaN                 FINANCE  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  8     USB         NaN                 FINANCE  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  9    ATVI         NaN  INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  10    HPQ         NaN  INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY  ...     13G  2022-04-30     2022-04-30
  11     BK         NaN                 FINANCE  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  12     KR         NaN        CONSUMER STAPLES  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  13    DVA         NaN             HEALTH CARE  ...     13D  2022-08-01     2022-08-01
  14      C         NaN                 FINANCE  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  15   VRSN         NaN          COMMUNICATIONS  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  16     GM         NaN  CONSUMER DISCRETIONARY  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  17   PARA         NaN          COMMUNICATIONS  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  18   CHTR         NaN          COMMUNICATIONS  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  19  LSXMK         NaN          COMMUNICATIONS  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  20      V         NaN                 FINANCE  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  21   AMZN         NaN  CONSUMER DISCRETIONARY  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  22    AON         NaN                 FINANCE  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  23     MA         NaN                 FINANCE  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  24   SNOW         NaN  INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY  ...     13F  2022-03-31     2022-05-16
  ```

Comment: You already have `driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()`, right?

Comment: It's Fantastic! In order to have 50 rows's table , can I modify this code?

Comment: Can I obtain 50 rows? in oter words can I modify the Java Table view throught Python ? Thanks

Comment: See, the challenge is that the `<table>` element **not** being not visible. I have added a commented line within the code block. Check if replacing with that line extracts all the rows.

Comment: OK, Clear! But i have a list of url. Is there a way to automatize this feature's table ? Thanks

Comment: Of coarse yes. There are other approaches as well.

Comment: Can you about it give me more information ?

Comment: Where is selenium room ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would analyse the Network tab for that page loading, you would notice an api being accessed via an XHR call, pulling this data into page. A more elegant way of obtaining that data - all 52 rows -  would be:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
url = 'https://whalewisdom.com/filer/holdings?id=berkshire-hathaway-inc&q1=-1&type_filter=1,2,3,4&symbol=&change_filter=&minimum_ranking=&minimum_shares=&is_etf=0&sc=true&sort=current_mv&order=desc&offset=0&limit=99'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['rows'])
print(df[:10])
```

This would return:

|  | symbol | permalink | security_type | name | sector | industry | current_shares | previous_shares | shares_change | position_change_type | percent_shares_change | current_ranking | previous_ranking | current_percent_of_portfolio | previous_percent_of_portfolio | current_mv | previous_mv | stock_id | percent_ownership | quarter_first_owned | quarter_id_owned | source_type | source_date | filing_date | avg_price | recent_price | quarter_end_price | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAPL | aapl | SH | Apple Inc | INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY | COMPUTERS & PERIPHERALS | 8.90923e+08 | 8.87136e+08 | 3.78786e+06 | addition | 0.427 | 1 | 1 | 42.2022 | 47.5985 | 1.55564e+11 | 1.57529e+11 | 195 | 5.50456 | Q1 2016 | 61 | 13F | 2022-03-31 | 2022-05-16 | 36.6604 | 166.13 | 174.61 |  |
| 1 | BAC | bac | SH | Bank of America Corp. (North Carolina National Bank) | FINANCE | BANKS | 1.0101e+09 | 1.0101e+09 | 0 |  | 0 | 2 | 2 | 11.2953 | 13.5788 | 4.16363e+10 | 4.49394e+10 | 205 | 12.5371 | Q3 2017 | 67 | 13F | 2022-03-31 | 2022-05-16 | 25.5185 | 33.64 | 41.22 |  |
| 2 | AXP | axp | SH | American Express Co | FINANCE | CONSUMER FINANCE | 1.51611e+08 | 1.51611e+08 | 0 |  | 0 | 3 | 3 | 7.69125 | 7.4946 | 2.83512e+10 | 2.48035e+10 | 368 | 20.1326 | Q1 2001 | 1 | 13F | 2022-03-31 | 2022-05-16 | 39.311 | 155.43 | 187 |  |
| 3 | CVX | cvx | SH | Chevron Corp. (Standard Oil of California) | ENERGY | INTEGRATED OIL & GAS | 1.59178e+08 | 3.8245e+07 | 1.20933e+08 | addition | 316.206 | 4 | 9 | 7.03142 | 1.3561 | 2.5919e+10 | 4.48806e+09 | 214 | 8.10144 | Q4 2020 | 80 | 13F | 2022-03-31 | 2022-05-16 | 125.342 | 155.36 | 162.83 |  |
| 4 | KO | ko | SH | Coca Cola Co. | CONSUMER STAPLES | BEVERAGES | 4e+08 | 4e+08 | 0 |  | 0 | 5 | 4 | 6.72786 | 7.1563 | 2.48e+10 | 2.3684e+10 | 386 | 9.22716 | Q1 2001 | 1 | 13F | 2022-03-31 | 2022-05-16 | 27.1275 | 63.92 | 62 |  |
| 5 | OXY | oxy | SH | Occidental Petroleum Corp. | ENERGY | INTEGRATED OIL & GAS | 2.26119e+08 | 2.20232e+08 | 5.88762e+06 | addition | 2.6734 | 6 | 999999 | 3.57628 | nan | 1.31828e+10 | 1.21326e+10 | 442 | 24.1274 | Q1 2022 | 85 | 4 | 2022-05-02 | 2022-05-04 | nan | 60.99 | nan |  |
| 6 | KHC | khc | SH | Kraft Heinz Co. (The) | CONSUMER STAPLES | FOOD PRODUCTS | 3.25635e+08 | 3.25635e+08 | 0 |  | 0 | 7 | 5 | 3.4797 | 3.5323 | 1.28268e+10 | 1.16903e+10 | 178038 | 26.6052 | Q3 2015 | 59 | 13F | 2022-03-31 | 2022-05-16 | 75.4858 | 37.34 | 39.39 |  |
| 7 | MCO | mco | SH | Moodys Corp | FINANCE | GENERAL FINANCE | 2.46698e+07 | 2.46698e+07 | 0 |  | 0 | 8 | 6 | 2.25813 | 2.9114 | 8.32383e+09 | 9.63552e+09 | 2707 | 13.3712 | Q1 2001 | 1 | 13F | 2022-03-31 | 2022-05-16 | 13.7106 | 309.92 | 337.41 |  |
| 8 | USB | usb | SH | U.S. Bancorp (First National Bank of Cincinnati) | FINANCE | BANKS | 1.26418e+08 | 1.26418e+08 | 0 |  | 0 | 9 | 8 | 1.82279 | 2.1456 | 6.71911e+09 | 7.10089e+09 | 471 | 8.50875 | Q1 2006 | 21 | 13F | 2022-03-31 | 2022-05-16 | 40.0713 | 47.66 | 53.15 |  |
| 9 | ATVI | atvi | SH | Activision Blizzard Inc | INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY | SOFTWARE | 6.43152e+07 | 1.46581e+07 | 4.96571e+07 | addition | 338.769 | 10 | 24 | 1.39774 | 0.2947 | 5.15229e+09 | 9.75205e+08 | 11336 | 8.2257 | Q4 2021 | 84 | 13F | 2022-03-31 | 2022-05-16 | 72.9554 | 80.59 | 80.11 |  |

Answer (score 0):

#### This is working for me. You can access each element using 'item'.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[11]/div/div/a/svg")))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

list_of_tr = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")))
for item in list_of_tr:
    stock = item.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[1]/a').text.strip()
    print(stock)
```